# Unity's game object is just a perfect example of objects in Object-Oriented Programming?

Tags: oop, object, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I would like to know the actual representations of game objects in Unity in terms of OOP languages.

I'll state this sentence and I want to know whether it's correct or not:

The game object that is found as a part of the hierarchy of Unity is nothing but a single object whose field members are variables that are referring to yet other objects that are called "components"

A second question:

Supposing this was correct, that these objects are actual objects in terms of OOP i.e. they are "instances of classes" , when do they get instantiated and when are they garbage collected ( usually ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main building blocks of Unity games are "GameObjects" and they work according to the "object composition" which is one object-oriented programming principle. However, in my opinion you shouldn't consider them as classes which can be derived/inherited/overrided but like containers or groups for classes written in C# or JS working together in one, physical object in OO way.

GameObject are instantiated during scene launch or when you try to instantiate them via code, for example:
`Instantiate(myGameObject, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);`

They are garbage collected when you:

- switch to another scene
- quit game/application
- call `Destroy(instantiatedGameObject);`